# How can i add a page.tpl.php for a page type and a language?

Tags: theming

I want to match a page--type-receipe.tpl.php for a page type but it doesn't work. I think the reason is the multi-language.

The page.tpl.php work without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because **page--type-receipe.tpl.php** [isn't a valid template suggestion](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656). If you're looking to theme a page by *node type* & *language*, you can do something like this to create your own theme suggestions inside your theme's **template.php**.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  global $language;

  if(isset($language->language) && isset($variables['node'])) {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'.$variables['node']->language.'__'.$variables['node']->type;
  }
}
```

This will let you make **page--en--recipe.tpl.php** a valid template file for a page showing a *recipe* node in *english*.